# Cannot get navbar right links to float right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie and cannot figure out how to get my links to float to the right:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="...">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-right">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Me</li>
        <li>Get in Touch</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me figure this simple task out?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img alt="Brand" src="...">
</a>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Me</li>
    <li>Get in Touch</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Take a look at the example "Right-Aligned Navigation Bar" of [Right Navigation](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

Right navigation is aligned by changing

```
class="nav navbar-nav" to class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have updated my answer and provided a link with an example. please try that.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I think somehow I didn't have my damn bootstrap css linked right.

Comment: Good. I believe it wouldn't be just linking of css. Right aligned css was also missing.